# Enum.values() vs EnumSet.allOf( ). Which one is more preferable?

Tags: java, enums

I looked under the hood for `EnumSet.allOf` and it looks very efficient, especially for enums with less than 64 values.

Basically all sets share the single array of all possible enum values and the only other piece of information is a bitmask which in case of `allOf` is set in one swoop.

On the other hand Enum.values() seems to be a bit of black magic. Moreover it returns an array, not a collection, so in many cases it must be decorated with Arrays.asList( ) to be usable in any place that expects collection.

So, should `EnumSet.allOf` be more preferable to `Enum.values`?

More specifically, which form of `for` iterator should be used:

```
for ( final MyEnum val: MyEnum.values( ) );
```

or

```
for ( final MyEnum val: EnumSet.allOf( MyEnum.class ) );
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Because I did not receive the answer to my question on which one is more efficient, I've decided to do some testing of my own.

I've tested iteration over `values()`, `Arrays.asList( values() )` and `EnumSet.allOf( )`.
I've repeated these tests 10,000,000 times for different enum sizes.  Here are the test results:

```
oneValueEnum_testValues         1.328
oneValueEnum_testList           1.687
oneValueEnum_testEnumSet        0.578

TwoValuesEnum_testValues        1.360
TwoValuesEnum_testList          1.906
TwoValuesEnum_testEnumSet       0.797

ThreeValuesEnum_testValues      1.343
ThreeValuesEnum_testList        2.141
ThreeValuesEnum_testEnumSet     1.000

FourValuesEnum_testValues       1.375
FourValuesEnum_testList         2.359
FourValuesEnum_testEnumSet      1.219

TenValuesEnum_testValues        1.453
TenValuesEnum_testList          3.531
TenValuesEnum_testEnumSet       2.485

TwentyValuesEnum_testValues     1.656
TwentyValuesEnum_testList       5.578
TwentyValuesEnum_testEnumSet    4.750

FortyValuesEnum_testValues      2.016
FortyValuesEnum_testList        9.703
FortyValuesEnum_testEnumSet     9.266
```

These are results for tests ran from command line.  When I ran these tests from Eclipse, I got overwhelming support for `testValues`.  Basically it was smaller than `EnumSet` even for small enums.  I believe that the performance gain comes from optimization of array iterator in `for ( val : array )` loop.

On the other hand, as soon as you need a java.util.Collection to pass around, `Arrays.asList( )` looses over to `EnumSet.allOf`, especially for small enums, which I believe will be a majority in any given codebase.

So, I would say you should use

```
for ( final MyEnum val: MyEnum.values( ) )
```

but

```
Iterables.filter(
    EnumSet.allOf( MyEnum.class ),
    new Predicate< MyEnum >( ) {...}
)
```

And only use `Arrays.asList( MyEnum.values( ) )` where `java.util.List` is absolutely required.

Answer (score 12):

You should use the approach which is simplest and clearest to you.  Performance shouldn't be a consideration in most situations.

IMHO: neither option performs very well as they both create objects. One in the first case and three in the second. You could construct a constant which holds all the values for performance reasons.

Comment: Its 2010, and creating an object is still not free. For most programming, creating objects doesn't matter, but if performance really does matter, the number of objects you create can make still make a difference.

Comment: I have worked on one project where each object created in the critical path costs over $200 per year.  So three objects can sound expensive in some contexts, especially if you do this more than once.

Comment: don't instantiate objects in a loop, instantiate it outside the loop.

Answer (score 8):

There is also `Class.getEnumConstants()`

under the hood they all call `values()` methods of enum types anyway, **through reflection**.

Comment: How does this relate to the question I've asked?

Comment: This relates to the question, because all the others use values() under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

The `values()` method is more clear and performant if you just want to iterate over all possible enum values. The values are cached by the class (see `Class.getEnumConstants()`)

If you need a subset of values, you should use an `EnumSet`. Start with `allOf()` or `noneOf()` and add or remove values or use just `of()` as you need.

Comment: The `values()` cannot be cached by the class, because it's an array and nothing will prevent the user from changing its values.  Hence, I suspect it must be a clone.  `EnumSet.allOf`, on the other hand does use a shared value for array, hence there is definitely less memory allocation here.  So, `values` may be more clear, but I suspect it's not more performant.

Comment: @Alexander: You are right, the array is cloned, but clone() is native. A little debugging shows me that getEnumConstants() uses values() not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I went through the entire implementation, but it seems to me that EnumSet.allOf() is basically using the same infrastructure as .values(). So I'd expect EnumSet.allOf() requires some (probably negligible) additional steps (see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6276988).

It seems clear to me that the intended use of foreach is `for(MyEnum val : MyEnum.values())` why do it differently? You will only confuse the maintenance programmer.

I mean, if you need a collection, you should get one. If you want to use a foreach, arrays are good enough. I'd even prefer arrays if pressed! Why wrap anything with anything, if what you got (array) is good enough? Simple things are normally faster.

In anyways, Peter Lawrey is right. Don't bother about the performance of this.. It's fast enough, and chances are there are million other bottlenecks that render that tiny theoretical performance difference as totally irrelevant (Don't see his "object creation" point though. To me the first example seems to be 100% OK).

Comment: @Zwei: see my comment to Arne's post

Comment: @Alexander: OK, so they fixed the bug (see link) in JDK6? Well, I see your point then, but still I maintain the answer to your question "More specifically, which form of for iterator should be used" as "use the first example". I mean, I don't know. If you are doing some development in embedded, real time app. or something, maybe it's justifiable. But in a normal, general context? No.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumSet` is not built with the intention to iterate over it's values. Rather it is implemented with the idea for it to represent a BitMap or BitMask efficiently (or reasonably efficient). The [javadoc on `EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) also states:

> Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if their argument is also an enum set.

Because only one single bit can represent a certain Enum value, it is also implemented as a `Set` and not as a `List`.

Now, it is probably also true that you can accomplish the same, and faster, using C-style bit masks (x^2), however it offers a more intuitive coding style and type safe use using enums, and it expands easily beyond the size of what an `int` or `long` can contain.

As such you can test that all bits are set as follows:

```
public class App {
  enum T {A,B}
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    EnumSet<T> t = EnumSet.of(T.A);
    t.containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(T.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: You got it absolutely backwards.  `EnumSet` first and foremost is a `Collection`, actually a `Set`.  Because of the properties of enums it turns out that the most efficient representation of such a set is a bit mask.  Also, notice that `containsAll` in your example is not unique to `EnumSet`, it is a method from `Set`.  But this aside, you did not answer the originally posted question, what form is more efficient when you need access to all values in the enum.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak substantiate what I have exactly backward as it is unclear to me. I never made any claims about `EnumSet` being anything other than a `Set`.  Consequently it comes natural that methods like `containsAll` and `retainAll` are not unique to `EnumSet`, although they have a completely unique implementation. As far as answers, you seemed to have provided an excellent one with metrics. I only intended to supplement because I do not believe choice should me made based only on an iteration over the complete set of enum values.

Comment: Sometimes iterating over the complete set of enum values is the only choice you have.  For example when you have to validate and assign externally passed value to enum, and that value does not clearly maps to enum name, so you cannot use `Enum.valueOf`.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak iterate once to build a `Map`, then use the map to translate your 'external value' to an `enum` constant. You can implement a convenience method that works similar to the built in `valueOf` method. Such approach makes your original question also irrelevant as building the map should happen only once as part of the static initialization of your `enum`.