# Getting the list of enum from an enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public class PaymentInterfaceFilesQueryLov
{
   public enum SelectableField
   {
      fileId, fileName, interfaceType, fileDate, fileUser, linesNumber, status, errorMsg
   }

   public enum ConditionalizableField
   {
      fileId, fileName, interfaceType, fileDate, fileUser, linesNumber, status, errorMsg
   }
```

I have this class and I want to extract the list of enum ConditionalizableField and put them on a list of String .
How to proceed ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of / related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2464950/1686330

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all values as array using  `YourEnumType.values();`. Then you can just iterate over arrays elements and add them to your list.

You can simplify your code with

```
List<ConditionalizableField> list = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(ConditionalizableField.values()));
```