# Does proguard converts all enums to int or needs to be configured for this

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums, proguard

Does proguard automatically converts enums to integer for memory optimization or I have to configure it to do this?
If I do have to configure what is the configuration?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The optimization is listed on ProGuard's [optimizations page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html). It appears to be one of the default optimizations, but it (like other optimizations) can be specified explicitly if you need more control (e.g. disabling all `class/*` optimizations aside from enum unboxing).

> **class/unboxing/enum**
>
> > Simplifies enum types to integer constants, whenever possible.

Comment: I just tried this and decompiled the code, but a simple enum class (only enums, no fields) still appears as an enum instead of an int. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm using the 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' file.

Comment: @ThomasVos Note that that file has a default specification to [keep static class members on enums](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android-optimize.txt#48), which may interfere with unboxing. I'd try removing that first, as long as you don't use the `values()` method or `String` conversion (which pretty much limits you to equality checks).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already removed those lines by copying the file into my source code, and remove the android proguard rules file in gradle. However, the enums still appear in the decompiled code.

Comment: @ThomasVos I also tried to verify enum conversion and for the first time it failed. But i managed to force a conversion. Look at this repository https://github.com/maxim-pandra/ProguardEnumIntDefTest

Comment: @MaksimTuraev What do you mean by "force a conversion"? I've checked out that repo, and it seems like it's still not converting enums to ints.

Comment: @yiati did you ran debug or release build? proguard in my repo configured to debug build. Then with apk analizer i could see converted enums. Please check build type. And tell if this was the problem. Are you using apk analyzer to see see convertion?

Comment: @MaksimTuraev I ran both debug and release, and used the apk analyzer. In both cases the `StateEnum` class is still 458 bytes with all of the class information.

Comment: @yiati. I have updated a sample. There was a mistake I forgot to push. Now enum converts to int, but the class itself doesn't get cleaned up entirely.

You can see an accepted issue here https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/724/.

Comment: @MaksimTuraev awesome that worked for me, thanks! I did add disable obfuscation to make it easier to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

### Proguard Settings

The Proguard needs to have the configuration like following:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Note the inclusion of the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file and not the `proguard-android.txt` file.

[ProguardEnumIntDefTest](https://github.com/maxim-pandra/ProguardEnumIntDefTest) is a sample project on Github that tries to find out if Proguard converts enums into ints.

---

### Optimization

For the Proguard to optimize an `enum`, that `enum` should not have methods and associated values(fields). Proguard converts these simple enums to ints so, you get the type-safety of the enums at compile-time and the performance of the ints at runtime!

---