# Identifier or type expected error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Developing a chalisa app where in this enum getting a error

[image]

[image]

```
public static enum AdState
      {
        static;
        {
          PROCESSING = new AdState("PROCESSING", 1);
          READY = new AdState("READY", 2);
          AdState[] arrayOfAdState = new AdState[3];
          arrayOfAdState[0] = UN_INITIALIZED;
          arrayOfAdState[1] = PROCESSING;
          arrayOfAdState[2] = READY;
          $VALUES = arrayOfAdState;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Look at this post, it might help you.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246934/working-with-enums-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246934/working-with-enums-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with Enums in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246934/working-with-enums-in-android)

Comment: thanks for answer can you check the code on Team viewer