# enumeration with assigning values to the enums

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert enum value to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157755/how-to-convert-enum-value-to-int)

I'm trying to assign values to my enums like:

```
enum it { one=5,two=7};
```

I can't beleive I can't remember how to do this.

Could someone help me??

Thank you very much

Comment: check out the [difference between enums in C# and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/469315/1106367) for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
enum it
{
    one(5), two(7);

    private int value;

    it(int value){this.value = value;}

    public int getValue(){return value;}
};
```

---

```
System.out.println(it.one.getValue());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
5
```