# value of what the enum is currently set to

Tags: java, enums

This should be total obvious, but it isn't. Is there a way to get the value of a enum as in the example below?

example:

```
    public enum Numbers
    {
        zero, one, two

    }

//later on
Numbers numbers = Numbers.zero;
// this is the part that I can not figure out the java equivalent of?
int number = numbers.value();
```

Does this make sense what I am trying to do?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal() - that said, it's not useful information. Why do you need to know?

Comment: ^^ "Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method."

I saw this in the documentation but it did not look like what I was needing... Is it though?

Comment: Well, since there's really no such thing as a "value" of an enum I don't know what it is you need. That'd be the closest thing to it as it's an integer that refers to the ordering.

Comment: I have an enum which keeps track of a state machine running on a thread, and I needed the value of the enum as a integer to integrate into another's part of it who used 30 something constant int's instead of a enum. :(

Comment: I would suggest checking out the Oracle tutorial on `enum` - you would want to define your own scheme for this that you pass in and provide a getter rather than relying on the ordinal.

Comment: Have you tried `valueOf`?

Comment: In an ideal world you would update the other part to use the enums instead of constants.  In the real world use ordinal() very carefully, or, define a method `int state()` that returns the int for the state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert enum value to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157755/how-to-convert-enum-value-to-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments it appears you need to map an integer value to your `enum` to integrate it into another part of your code.

Rather than relying on the ordering you really want to do this yourself:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ZERO(0), ONE(1), TWO(2);

    private int mapping;

    MyEnum(int mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }

    public int getMapping() {
        return mapping;
    }

}
```

You could then compare via:

```
MyEnum e = MyEnum.ZERO;
if (someInt == e.getMapping()) { ... }
```

(Or even just `MyEnum.ZERO.getMapping()` )

Comment: I up voted everyone since they are all valid answers, however you were the first to start helping and I thank you for your help, so I accepted yours.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally considered bad practice to rely on `ordinal` since it is based on the order of the `enum` constants. A better solution would be to pass information to each instance. Just write a constructor and method like this:

```
public enum Number {
    ZERO(0), ONE(1), TWO(2);

    private int value;

    private Number(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int value() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Then you use it like you want

```
Number numbers = Number.ZERO;
int number = numbers.value();
```

and you won't have to worry about the actual order of the code if you add `Number`s later.

Note: It is idiomatic in Java for `enum` names to be singular and for constants to be uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ordinal()` method.  However, this is *discouraged / risky*, since if you ever change the order or arrangements of your enums, it will fail.  e.g., you change to powers of two

```
public enum Numbers {
   zero, one, two, four
}
```

then four.ordinal() will be 3.

If you really want a number associated with the enum, you should define your own method, e.g. `order()` or whatever.  In the initial implementation it could return `ordinal()`, but, when you add `four` in the future, you can update that method.

p.s.  Standard style is to capitalize the enums, e.g. ZERO, ONE, etc...

Comment: Thank you, this is what i needed. The actual emun I am using is not zero, one, two, three, it is 30something differing states, and for my portion of it at least, this enum's ordering will never be changed.

Comment: Ideally I'd still define a method `int state()`, but using ordinal is tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need. Here are 2 use cases:

1) You will probably need to test the value of an incoming "Numbers". For this use case, a switch case is the best solution.

```
void myMethod(Numbers n){

  switch(n){
    case zero:
    //do something
    break;

    case one:
    //do something
    break;

    //etc.
  }
}
```

2) You can calso need to assign a value to each Numbers and be able to retrieve it. For this use case, you can define a constructor for your enum

```
public enum Numbers
{
    zero(0), one(1), two(2);

    private int value;

    private Numbers(int value){
      this.value=value;
    }

}
```

Then, in your code, you can get this value:

```
void myMethod(Numbers n){
  int value = n.getValue();
  //do something with this value...
}
```

Last remark : Your enum names don't follow the java convention. They should be named with uppercase letters and eventually character '_'. ex: ONE, TWO, THREE, ANOTHER_VALUE