# How to convert my enumeration code into a switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

In my `CustomerTypeApp` class, I need to change the `getDiscountPercent` method to use a switch instead of a chain of if statements. Here is the if statement version:

```
public static double getDiscountPercent(CustomerType ct) {
        double discountPercent = 0;
        if (ct == CustomerType.RETAIL) {
            discountPercent = 0.156;
        } else if (ct == CustomerType.TRADE) {
            discountPercent = 0.30;
        } else if (ct == CustomerType.COLLEGE) {
            discountPercent = 0.20;
        }
        return discountPercent;
    }
}
```

Below is the switch statement I have tried, but which receives the error:

> An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant

```
  double discountPercent = 0;

  switch(ct) {
      case CustomerType.RETAIL :
        discountPercent = 0.156;
        break;
     case CustomerType.TRADE :
        discountPercent = 0.30;
        break;
     case CustomerType.COLLEGE :
        discountPercent = 0.20;
        break;
     default :
        discountPercent = 0;
  }
  return discountPercent;
```

Comment: Are you facing any *specific* problem while writing your code which would involve switch? This looks like homework task so can't simply spoon feed you solution without seeing any honest attempt first.

Comment: From the above, you don't seem to have tried to use `switch` (yet). Your best bet is to try to use it, and then post a question **if** you run into a specific problem doing so. (Converting the above to `switch` is very straightforward, you won't run into a problem.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java using enum with switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108980)

Comment: `switch(ct)` knows what is type of `ct` so `CustomerType.` part is not necessary in `case` part

Comment: Pshemo is right. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109054/7098259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(It's Very Simple)

```
public static double getDiscountPercent(CustomerType ct) {

      double discountPercent = 0;

      switch(ct) {
         case CustomerType.RETAIL :
            discountPercent = 0.156;
            break;
         case CustomerType.TRADE :
            discountPercent = 0.30;
            break;
         case CustomerType.COLLEGE :
            discountPercent = 0.20;
            break;
         default :
            discountPercent = 0;
      }
      return discountPercent;

   }
```

Comment: I had tried this thinking it didn't work. I get the error message "An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant"

Comment: @AveryO To get better help use edit option under your question and include your invalid code along with error message.

Comment: how is your enumeration declared?

Answer (score 1):

You want to switch for the variable ct

```
switch(ct) {
        case CustomeType.retail:
            /*Command*/
            break;
        case CustomerType.TRADE:
            /*Command*/
            break;
        default:
            /*else*/
}
```

If you need further help read [these Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)