# What's the advantage of a Java enum versus a class with public static final fields?

Tags: java, enums

I am very familiar with C# but starting to work more in Java. I expected to learn that enums in Java were basically equivalent to those in C# but apparently this is not the case. Initially I was excited to learn that Java enums could contain multiple pieces of data which seems very advantageous (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). However, since then I have found a lot of features missing that are trivial in C#, such as the ability to easily assign an enum element a certain value, and consequently the ability to convert an integer to an enum without a decent amount of effort (i.e. [Convert integer value to matching Java Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292790/convert-integer-value-to-matching-java-enum)).

So my question is this: is there any benefit to Java enums over a class with a bunch of public static final fields? Or does it just provide more compact syntax?

EDIT: Let me be more clear. What is the benefit of Java enums over a class with a bunch of public static final fields *of the same type*? For example, in the planets example at the first link, what is the advantage of an enum over a class with these public constants:

```
public static final Planet MERCURY = new Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
public static final Planet VENUS = new Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);
public static final Planet EARTH = new Planet(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6);
public static final Planet MARS = new Planet(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6);
public static final Planet JUPITER = new Planet(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7);
public static final Planet SATURN = new Planet(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7);
public static final Planet URANUS = new Planet(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7);
public static final Planet NEPTUNE = new Planet(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);
```

As far as I can tell, casablanca's answer is the only one that satisfies this.

Comment: @Bohemian: It may not be a duplicate, since the OP only mentioned `public static final` fields, which may be typed values and not necessarily `int`s.

Comment: You should not be using `Enums` just to replace `String Constants`. Thats like taking an armored vehicle to withdraw $10 from atm. Enums as many have exaplained are full blown final singleton classes that can have behaviour and data both.

Comment: @Shahzeb Hardly. Clearly using enums instead of string constants is an EXTREMELY good idea and more than encouraged. Type-safety, doesn't need static utility functions, and so on.. absolutely no reason to use strings instead.

Comment: @Voo Yes I knew there will be disagreements .And here is one in 49 seconds. Enums are great (and I love them and use them very often) but What type safety do you need when declaring a constant or using it. It is an overkill to create enum every time you need to declare a constant for String literal .

Comment: @Shahzeb If you have a single variable, sure use a string, not much can happen here (a single value is rather pointless as a parameter). But note that we're talking about constant`S`, so now we're talking about probably passing them into functions, etc. Do we *need* type-saftey? Well, no, but then most people consider c-style types of "everything's a `void*`" good style and it can stop bugs (especially if passing more than one enum/string parameter!). Also it puts the constants into their own namespace, etc. Contrary to that, there's no real advantage to just have plain variables.

Comment: @Voo yeap agree. please do not delete your comment. I think we have added some meta value here :)

Comment: @casablanca public static final ints or objects, the reasoning vs enums is identical

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't see how. With `int`s, there is no type safety because one could pass any value. Typed objects, on the other hand, are no different from enums in terms of type safety.

Comment: @Bohemian: Couldn't you just make the Planet constructor private? That would fix your issue.

Comment: @Craig Good idea - it does help, but you can "hack" a private constructor via reflection so it's not a safe as you might think. Also, once you have a private constructor with static final constants, why not use an enum which enforces that pattern from the language? Also, IDEs can prompt the user to select from enum values a bit more readily than from class constants, although I grant you that both share that `Class.NAME` syntax.

Comment: @Bohemian: True but if that's the case nothing is really private and there are bigger problems. Your point about the language enforcing the pattern is well taken though. My question was intended to figure out what the other benefits of enums are that I might have missed. Apparently there are not that many. And it's disappointing that converting from an integer to an enum value and especially vice versa is not trivial like it is in C#.

Comment: @Bohemian: Anything can be "hacked" -- even an enum can be changed by instrumentation right before it is loaded. I think the question is whether enums are really "special" in some way and they really are not, they're just convenient to use.

Comment: Re: Enums vs String constants. The issue isn't direct replacement but what their *purpose* in the code is. If they're being passed to a function that expects a value from a closed set of values then enums make more sense. If they're just something, say, that shows up on the screen, it makes less sense (although I'd argue then they should be properties, e.g., I18N, instead of plain old variables).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Technically one could indeed view enums as a class with a bunch of typed constants, and this is in fact how enum constants are implemented internally. Using an `enum` however gives you useful methods ([Enum javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)) that you would otherwise have to implement yourself, such as `Enum.valueOf`.

Comment: There is also `.values()` to iterate over the list of values.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer, although it's not very satisfying. In my opinion it was barely worthwhile for Java to add support for enums just for the more compact syntax and access to the Enum methods.

Comment: @Craig your instincts are right - this is a very bad answer, because it missed entirely the purpose of enums. See my comments under the question for part of the reasons why.

Comment: @Craig: Sometimes compact syntax (aka syntactic sugar) is really what's required. For example, properties in C# are also just syntactic sugar for hidden get/set methods.

Comment: @Bohemian: I didn't "miss the purpose" of enums -- I use them all the time. See my response to your comment above.

Comment: Enum.valuesOf method does return same object if called twice?

Comment: @EmreAktürk Yes, that is built into the specification.

Comment: Very bare bone answer, doesn't qualify to be accepted for this question.

Answer (score 141):

1. Type safety and value safety.
2. Guaranteed singleton.
3. Ability to define and override methods.
4. Ability to use values in `switch` statement `case` statements without qualification.
5. Built-in sequentialization of values via `ordinal().`
6. Serialization by name not by value, which offers a degree of future-proofing.
7. `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` classes.

Comment: Having said all that, every time I've put code into an Enum I've regretted it.

Comment: Why did you regret it? I did never…

Comment: @glglgl Becasue it put application-specific code into a place where I felt it was didn't really belong, that was really only defining a set of values. If I had it to do again I would have included it in one of the numerous `switch` statements that were the original motivation for using an `Enum` at all.

Answer (score 78):

Nobody mentioned the ability to use them in `switch` statements; I'll throw that in as well.

This allows arbitrarily complex enums to be used in a clean way without using `instanceof`, potentially confusing `if` sequences, or non-string/int switching values. The canonical example is a state machine.

Comment: Anyway, You didn't mentioned any benefits from enums vs static fields, You can use enough types in switch statements with static fields. Op Need real functionals or  perfomance differences

Comment: @Genaut The benefit is that enums have more functionality than a string or int-the question was about differences, which I provided. The OP is already aware of what enums are, and nobody else had mentioned switch statements when I posted this 4.5 yrs ago, and at least a few people found it provided new info ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Genaut how do you switch over `Planet` instances when `Planet` is not an `enum`?

Answer (score 58):

The primary advantage is type safety. With a set of constants, any value of the same intrinsic type could be used, introducing errors.  With an enum only the applicable values can be used.

For example

```
public static final int SIZE_SMALL  = 1;
public static final int SIZE_MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int SIZE_LARGE  = 3;

public void setSize(int newSize) { ... }

obj.setSize(15); // Compiles but likely to fail later
```

vs

```
public enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE };

public void setSize(Size s) { ... }

obj.setSize( ? ); // Can't even express the above example with an enum
```

Comment: classes are also type safe ... :/ (assuming static field are of the type of the container class)

Comment: You could still pass it an invalid value but it would be a compile time error which is much easier to spot.

Comment: You could call `setSize(null)` in your second example, but it is likely to fail much sooner than the first example's error.

Answer (score 45):

There is less confusion. Take [`Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) for instance. It has a constructor that takes the name of the `Font` you want, its size and its style (`new Font(String, int, int)`). To this day I cannot remember if style or size goes first. If `Font` had used an `enum` for all of its different styles (`PLAIN`, `BOLD`, `ITALIC`, `BOLD_ITALIC`), its constructor would look like `Font(String, Style, int)`, preventing any confusion. Unfortunately, `enum`s weren't around when the `Font` class was created, and since Java has to maintain reverse compatibility, we will always be plagued by this ambiguity.

Of course, this is just an argument for using an `enum` instead of `public static final` constants. Enums are also perfect for [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_enum_way) and implementing default behavior while allowing for later customization (I.E. the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)). An example of the latter is `java.nio.file`'s [`OpenOption`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/OpenOption.html) and [`StandardOpenOption`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html): if a developer wanted to create his own non-standard `OpenOption`, he could.

Comment: Your 'Font' case is still ambiguous if two of the same enums were asked for.  The canonical answer to that problem is what many languages call [Named Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter).  That or better IDE method signature support.

Comment: @aaaaaa I haven't seen many cases where a constructor would take two of the same `enum` without using [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) or a `Set` to take an arbitrary number of them.

Comment: @aaaaaa The main issue with named parameters it relies on implementation details (the name of the parameter). I can make an interface `interface Foo { public void bar(String baz); }`. Someone makes a class which invokes `bar`: `someFoo.bar(baz = "hello");`. I change the signature of `Foo::bar` to `public void bar(String foobar)`. Now the person who called `someFoo` will need to modify their code if they still want it to work.

Comment: I don't remember seeing consecutive enum types either, but thought a common one might be DAY_OF_WEEK or something similar.  And good point about the interface - hadn't thought of that.  Personally I would take that problem over the widespread ambiguity caused by un-named parameters, necessitating stronger IDE support.  I understand that's a judgement call however, and that breaking API changes are something to seriously consider.

Answer (score 32):

There are many good answers here, but none mentiones that there are **highly optimized implementations** of the Collection API classes/interfaces **specifically for enums**:

- [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)
- [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)

These enum specific classes only accept `Enum` instances (the `EnumMap` only accept `Enum`s only as keys), and whenever possible, they revert to compact representation and bit manipulation in their implementation.

**What does this mean?**

If our `Enum` type has no more that 64 elements (most of real-life `Enum` examples will qualify for this), the implementations store the elements in a single `long` value, each `Enum` instance in question will be associated with a bit of this 64-bit long `long`. Adding an element to an `EnumSet` is simply just setting the proper bit to 1, removing it is just setting that bit to 0. Testing if an element is in the `Set` is just one bitmask test! Now you gotta love `Enum`s for this!

Comment: I knew about these two before, but I just learned a lot from your `What does this mean?` section. I knew there was a divide in implementation at size 64, but I didn't actually know why

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the `EnumSet` has the same optimizations for types containing more than 64 constants as well. It just has to use a `long[]` array instead of a single `long`. And while reducing `add`, `remove`, and `contains` operations to single bit operations is great, the real fun starts with operations like `addAll`, `removeAll`, and `retainAll` which do not go bit by bit but process 64 elements (in other words, all of them, usually) at once.

Answer (score 20):

example:

```
public class CurrencyDenom {
  public static final int PENNY = 1;
  public static final int NICKLE = 5;
  public static final int DIME = 10;
  public static final int QUARTER = 25;
}
```

Limitation of java Constants

1. **No Type-Safety**: First of all it’s not type-safe; you can assign any valid int value to int e.g. 99 though there is no coin to represent that value.
2. **No Meaningful Printing**: printing value of any of these constant will print its numeric value instead of meaningful name of coin e.g. when you print NICKLE it will print "5" instead of "NICKLE"
3. **No namespace**: to access the currencyDenom constant we need to prefix class name e.g. CurrencyDenom.PENNY instead of just using PENNY though this can also be achieved by using static import in JDK 1.5

Advantage of enum

1. Enums in Java are type-safe and has there own name-space. It means your enum will have a type for example "Currency" in below example and you can not assign any value other than specified in Enum Constants.

   public enum Currency {PENNY, NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER};
   `Currency coin = Currency.PENNY; coin = 1; //compilation error`
2. Enum in Java are reference type like class or interface and you can define constructor, methods and variables inside java Enum which makes it more powerful than Enum in C and C++ as shown in next example of Java Enum type.
3. You can specify values of enum constants at the creation time as shown in below example:
   public enum Currency {PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25)};
   But for this to work you need to define a member variable and a constructor because PENNY (1) is actually calling a constructor which accepts int value , see below example.

   public enum Currency {
   PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
   private int value;

   private Currency(int value) {
   this.value = value;
   }
   };

Reference: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 11):

The first benefit of enums, as you have already noticed, is syntax simplicity. But the main point of enums is to provide a well-known set of constants which, by default, form a range and help to perform more comprehensive code analysis through type & value safety checks.

Those attributes of enums help both a programmer and a compiler. For example, let's say you see a function that accepts an integer. What that integer could mean? What kind of values can you pass in? You don't really know right away. But if you see a function that accepts enum, you know very well all possible values you can pass in.

For the compiler, enums help to determine a range of values and unless you assign special values to enum members, they are well ranges from 0 and up. This helps to automatically track down errors in the code through type safety checks and more. For example, compiler may warn you that you don't handle all possible enum values in your switch statement (i.e. when you don't have `default` case and handle only one out of N enum values). It also warns you when you convert an arbitrary integer into enum because enum's range of values is less than integer's and that in turn may trigger errors in the function that doesn't really accept an integer. Also, generating a jump table for the switch becomes easier when values are from 0 and up.

This is not only true for Java, but for other languages with a strict type-checking as well. C, C++, D, C# are good examples.

Answer (score 7):

enum Benefits:

1. Enums are type-safe, static fields are not
2. There is a finite number of values (it is not possible to pass non-existing enum value. If you have static class fields, you can make that mistake)
3. Each enum can have multiple properties (fields/getters) assigned - encapsulation. Also some simple methods: YEAR.toSeconds() or similar. Compare: Colors.RED.getHex() with Colors.toHex(Colors.RED)

*"such as the ability to easily assign an enum element a certain value"*

```
enum EnumX{
  VAL_1(1),
  VAL_200(200);
  public final int certainValue;
  private X(int certainValue){this.certainValue = certainValue;}
}
```

*"and consequently the ability to convert an integer to an enum without a decent amount of effort"*
Add a method converting int to enum which does that. Just add static HashMap<Integer, EnumX> containing the mapping.

If you really want to convert ord=VAL_200.ordinal() back to val_200 just use: EnumX.values()[ord]

Answer (score 6):

An enum is implictly final, with a private constructors, all its values are of the same type or a sub-type, you can obtain all its values using `values()`, gets its `name()` or `ordinal()` value or you can look up an enum by number or name.

You can also define subclasses (even though notionally final, something you can't do any other way)

```
enum Runner implements Runnable {
    HI {
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Hello");
       }
    }, BYE {
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Sayonara");
       }
       public String toString() {
           return "good-bye";
       }
    }
 }

 class MYRunner extends Runner // won't compile.
```

Comment: To add on to this answer, you can also have a "default" implementation of any method defined in the interface. That way, not every enum needs to have the curly braces and a method implementation. You can simply provide an inline implementation for the enum values that need it.

Answer (score 3):

You get compile time checking of valid values when you use an enum.  Look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages)

Answer (score 3):

Another important difference is that java compiler treats `static final` fields of **primitive types** and **String** as literals. It means these constants become inline. It's similar to `C/C++` `#define` preprocessor. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927107/define-in-java). This is not the case with enums.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest advantage is enum Singletons are easy to write and thread-safe :

```
public enum EasySingleton{
    INSTANCE;
}
```

and

```
/**
* Singleton pattern example with Double checked Locking
*/
public class DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton{
     private volatile DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton INSTANCE;

     private DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton(){}

     public DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton getInstance(){
         if(INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized(DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton.class){
                //double checking Singleton instance
                if(INSTANCE == null){
                    INSTANCE = new DoubleCheckedLockingSingleton();
                }
            }
         }
         return INSTANCE;
     }
}
```

both are similar and it handled Serialization by themselves by implementing

```
//readResolve to prevent another instance of Singleton
    private Object readResolve(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

[more](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

## Enums can be local

As of [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16), an enum can be defined locally (within a method). This scope is in addition to being able to define an enum as nested or as separate class.

This new local definition scope came along with the new records feature. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for details. Enums, interfaces, and records can all be defined locally in Java 16+.

In contrast, `public static final` fields always have global scope.

Comment: Part of the same change, is that local classes now can have `static final` fields. Their scope would be the same as for the constants of a local `enum`. However, when you’re within an instance method, ordinary local classes still have an implicit reference to the surrounding `this`, which prevents them from being used like an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages of enums that are posted here, here is my take on this.

Say you have an enum with many fields - 5,6 or more.

```
enum Planet{
EARTH(1000000, 312312321,31232131, "some text", "", 12),
....
other planets
....
```

In such a case when you have multiple fields in an enum, it is much more difficult to understand which value belongs to which field as you need to see the constructor and eyeball.

Class with `static final` constants and using the `Builder` pattern make it more readable. But, you would lose all other advantages of using an enum.
One other point if you are maintaining a list of Planet objects somewhere, you would need to update the list too.

I personally would prefer an enum over such a class, as `values()` comes in handy and you never know if you need them to use in `switch` or `EnumSet` or `EnumMap` in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I think an `enum` can't be `final`, because under the hood compiler generates subclasses for each `enum` entry.

More information From [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734225/what-are-the-differences-between-a-java-enum-and-a-class-with-private-constructo/15734503#15734503)

Comment: Internally, they are not final, because – as you say – can internally be subclassed. But alas, you cannot subclass them on your own, e. g. for extending it with own values.

Comment: A subclass is only generated when you request it explicitly. Then, the subclasses will be `final`. Otherwise, the `enum` type itself will be `final`.

Answer (score 0):

**Main reason:** Enums help you to write well-structured code where the semantic meaning of parameters is clear and strongly-typed at compile time - for all the reasons other answers have given.

**Quid pro quo:** in Java out of the box, an Enum's array of members is final.  That's normally good as it helps value safety and testing, but in some situations it could be a drawback, for example if you are extending existing base code perhaps from a library. In contrast, if the same data is in a class with static fields you can easily add new instances of that class at runtime (you might also need to write code to add these to any Iterable you have for that class).  But this behaviour of Enums can be changed: using reflection you can add new members at runtime or replace existing members, though this should probably only be done in specialised situations where there is no alternative: i.e. it's a hacky solution and may produce unexpected issues, see my answer on [Can I add and remove elements of enumeration at runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918808/7867094).

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
public enum Size { SMALL(1), MEDIUM(2), LARGE(3) };

private int sizeValue;

Size(sizeValue) {this.sizeValue = value; }
```

So with this you can get size value like this SMALL.getSizeValue();

If you want to set sizes Enums are not for you, if you will be only define constants and fixed values are fine.

Check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-values) maybe can help you