# what is the difference between enum and Enum ?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

Please help me by answering the difference between Enum and enum in java. I tried searching the various answers present in this below link but it seems to be not much helpful.

[difference between Enum and enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808770/difference-between-enum-and-enum)

Comment: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-an-enum-type-and-javalangenum/186 (from google answers)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15734503/180100

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.Enum` is an abstract class, it is the common base class of all Java enumeration types while `enum` it's a category of classes that extend the `Enum` base class.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` is a keyword used to define an enumerated type, like `class` is used to define a class:

```
public enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN }
```

`Enum` is the simple name of the [`java.lang.Enum` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), which is the superclass of all enumerated types defined using the enum keyword.

They're not really comparable. They're different things. `enum` is to `Enum` what the keyword `class` is to `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` (a datatype) *extends* the abstract class `Enum` under the hood.
This will give you access to methods like ordinal(), found in `Enum` class.

From `Enum` abstract class definition(the first line):

> This is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types.

An example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(Color.BLUE.ordinal()); //prints 1
    }
}

enum Color{
    RED, BLUE, YELLOW
}
```

**BONUS:**
You might want to check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sI4utYmh7O4). There are 3 short videos.

Enjoy and cheers.