# One-liner to instantiate a Collection of enums with a common interface

Tags: java, generics, collections, enums

I have two enums that implement a common interface. I've tried to declare the interface so only enums can implement it.

```
interface CommonEnumInterface<E extends Enum<?>> {

    /** It doesn't matter what this does. */
    E commonInterfaceMethod();

}

enum Enum1 implements CommonEnumInterface<Enum1> {
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ;

    @Override
    public Enum1 commonInterfaceMethod() {
        return null;
    }
}

enum Enum2 implements CommonEnumInterface<Enum2> {
    BLAH,
    YADDA,
    RHUBARB;

    @Override
    public Enum2 commonInterfaceMethod() {
        return Enum2.BLAH;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create another enum, where each constant has its own Set of elements of type `CommonEnumInterface`, but not necessarily the same class. Every way I've found feels like a hack, though, especially for cases where I want each constant to declared with more than one set of elements.

These comments show what I've tried. Is there a more elegant way (that compiles)?

```
enum CreatingAnotherEnumAttempt {

    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Enum<?>&CommonEnumInterface<?>> to List<CommonEnumInterface<?>>
    A(Arrays.asList(Enum1.FOO, Enum2.BLAH)),

    // Cannot cast from List<Enum<?>&CommonEnumInterface<?>> to List<CommonEnumInterface<?>>
    B((List<CommonEnumInterface<?>>) Arrays.asList(Enum1.FOO, Enum2.BLAH)),

    // This works, but it generates type safety warnings, and it's hard to read.
    C(Arrays.asList((CommonEnumInterface<?>) Enum1.FOO, (CommonEnumInterface<?>) Enum2.BLAH)),

    // This is the best I've come up with.
    D(getMixOfElements(Enum1.FOO, Enum2.BLAH));

    /**
     * I want to populate this set in the constructor.
     */
    private final Set<CommonEnumInterface<?>> mixOfElements;

    /**
     * I tried declaring the Set this way, but wildcards can extend only one interface, so there's a syntax error at the ampersand.
     */
    private final Set<? extends Enum<?> & CommonEnumInterface<?>> mixOfElements;

    /**
     * This is the constructor I'm trying to satisfy.
     *
     * @param mixOfElements I could make this a varargs parameter, but that only works for a single set of elements. What if I want more?
     */
    private CreatingAnotherEnumAttempt(List<CommonEnumInterface<?>> mixOfElements) {
        this.mixOfElements = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<CommonEnumInterface<?>>(mixOfElements));
    }

    /**
     * This method only exists to allow method {@link #D}. It's pretty pointless, otherwise.
     *
     * @param mixOfElements the mix of elements
     * @return the mix of elements as a list
     */
    private static List<CommonEnumInterface<?>> getMixOfElements(CommonEnumInterface<?>... mixOfElements) {
        return Arrays.asList(mixOfElements);
    }

    /**
     * This works without type safety warnings or superfluous methods, but for my constructor, I need a one-liner.
     */
    private static void wayThatWorksInline() {
        Collection<CommonEnumInterface<?>> inlineWay = new ArrayList<CommonEnumInterface<?>>();
        inlineWay.add(Enum1.FOO);
        inlineWay.add(Enum2.BLAH);
    }

}
```

My question is above, and in the code comments. Generally, is this the right way to declare my interface?

Comment: Any reason for the requirement that it be enums? Couldn't you just use classes with public static final members?

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for encouraging me to take a step back, but in practice, yes, there are a lot of reasons I'm using enums. Some of them are mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel

Comment: Good, well-written question by the way +1

Comment: @Paul: Cheers. I was hoping I'd at least get some credit for that, but your answer is the real win. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that enums are involved is actually a diversion, since simply passing a `List<CommonEnumInterface<?>>` into the constructor is your goal. To achieve that, do the following:

```
A(Arrays.<CommonEnumInterface<?>>asList(Enum1.FOO, Enum2.BLAH)),

//etc.
```

The problem was type inference - sometimes it gets a little too eager. Based on the arguments `Enum1.FOO` and `Enum2.BLAH` to `asList`, the compiler inferred `Enum<?>&CommonEnumInterface<?>` for `T`, and so a `List<Enum<?>&CommonEnumInterface<?>>` was returned. Since [generics aren't covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), this wasn't assignable to `List<CommonEnumInterface<?>>`. Specifying the type argument for `T` manually solves this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I will try and give this a shot. You can try using the dynamic type.

```
List<CommonEnumInterface<dynamic>>
or
List<dynamic>
```

Or go with a more noobish but clean solution

```
public class MyEnums
{
    List<Tuple<Enum, string>> myEnums;
    public void addEnum(Enum Enum, string EnumName)
    {
        myEnums.Add(new Tuple<Enum, string>(Enum, EnumName));
    }

    public List<Tuple<Enum, string>> getEnums()
    {
        return myEnums;
    }

    public Enum getEnumByName(string EnumName)
    {
        return myEnums.Where(n => n.Item2 == EnumName).Select(n => n.Item1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class myEnums
{
    public dynamic s { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not C#. There is no "dynamic" keyword.

Comment: How would a Hashtable help? ``Hashtable<CommonEnumInterface<?>,?>`` ...?? Or is that a pun on C#? ;-)

Comment: @Pierre: Thanks for elaborating. That's a good trick, but this is a cleaner solution for the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21036925/1450294

Comment: @MichaelScheper Sweet :) will remember when I am in your situation. Java ofcourse :D