# Strange behavior with Java enums

Tags: java, enums

I run into strange behavior with java Enums. If you write next enum:

```
public enum Test {
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

You got a compilation error, it is expected because you did not declare enum constants in the beginning.

But the strange part is if you just add a semicolon without a constant name in the beginning:

```
public enum Test {
   ;
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

Your code will be compiled successfully.

Maybe my question is dumb and there is an answer in java specification but I have not found one yet.

If someone understands why java compiler does so, please explain.

Comment: Perhaps this can help understand a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26619349/4121573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another answer pointed out, the relevant section of the JLS is 8.9, specifically [8.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) which states:

> The body of an enum declaration may contain enum constants. An enum constant defines an instance of the enum type.
>
> *`EnumBody:`*
>   
>      *`{ [EnumConstantList] [,] [EnumBodyDeclarations] }`*

To understand the meaning of the `EnumBody` definition one must look at [JLS Chapter 2.4, Grammar Notation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4), which says

> The syntax {x} on the right-hand side of a production denotes zero or
>   more occurrences of x.

Also that

> The syntax [x] on the right-hand side of a production denotes zero or
>   one occurrences of x. That is, x is an optional symbol. The
>   alternative which contains the optional symbol actually defines two
>   alternatives: one that omits the optional symbol and one that includes
>   it.

How does this relate to your question? It means valid enum declarations are the following (some grammar notation follows, bear with me):

```
public enum Test {
}

public enum Test {
  [EnumConstantList]
}

public enum Test {
  [EnumConstantList] ,
}

public enum Test {
 ,
}

public enum Test {
  [EnumBodyDeclarations]
}

public enum Test {
 , [EnumBodyDeclarations]
}

public enum Test {
  [EnumConstantList] [EnumBodyDeclarations]
}

public enum Test {
  [EnumConstantList] , [EnumBodyDeclarations]
}
```

`[EnumConstantList]` is not that interesting because it's what one would expect:

*`EnumConstant {, EnumConstant}`*

That is, one or more `EnumConstant` separated by commas (I'm not going into the definition of `EnumConstant`, I've fallen into a deep enough rabbit hole plus it's not relevant to the question).

Things get interesting (finally) with the definition of [`[EnumBodyDeclarations]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

> *`EnumBodyDeclarations:`*
>   
>   *`; {ClassBodyDeclaration}`*

### This is why your first example is invalid

You incorrectly specified `EnumBodyDeclarations` which as the above excerpt shows is a non-optional semicolon followed by zero or more `ClassBodyDeclaration`.

### This is why your second example is valid

It contains the non-optional semicolon followed by a valid `ClassBodyDeclaration`.

Phew.

This also means the following are valid enum declarations:

```
public enum Test {
 ;
}

public enum Test {
 ,;
}

public enum Test {
   ,;
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}

public enum Test {
   CAT,
}

public enum Test {
   CAT;
}

public enum Test {
   CAT,;
}

public enum Test {
   CAT,;
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}

public enum Test {
   CAT;
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

#### but never

```
public enum Test {
   CAT,
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to write so сomprehensive answer! Do you test these enum declarations? Second and third one are not compiled. Thus right declaration for enum body should be:
{ [EnumConstantList [,]]  [EnumBodyDeclarations] }

Comment: I tested them all and they all compiled with Java 8, including the second and third examples.  What version of Java are you using and what is the compiler's complaint?

Comment: Sorry, I built my project with maven and I didn't notice that build failed during validation phase not compile. It happened because I add checkstyle plugin to pom.

Answer (score 2):

Means you are creating an empty enum . An enum by default should have few enumerated values. So the semicolon here is treated as empty enum . It is a bad practice to create such enums

Answer (score 1):

Java enums can have fields and methods as well as regular enum values:

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE;

  public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

What you're creating by putting the semicolon there is just an enum without any values. Fairly useless, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

An enum body must contain the enum constants, and *optionally* other class components (methods etc.).

See the [Java Language Spec section 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Your first example declares no constants and a public final static field. Your second example contains an *empty* list of constants first (and is counterintuitively valid)

You can take your second example and add an enum constant e.g.

```
public enum Test {
   INSERTED_ENUM;
   public static final int C1 = 5;
}
```

to further demonstrate this.