# Correct way to define Predicates and Functions

Tags: java, enums, guava, predicate

When defining [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html)'s or [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html)'s, I used to create them as `static final`

```
private static final Predicate<SomeDto> SOME_PREDICATE =
                new Predicate<SomeDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(SomeDto input) {
                        return input.isValid();
                    }
                }
```

However I have noticed that there is a lot of use also with `enum` version, for example

```
private enum SomePredicate implements Predicate<SomeDto> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public boolean apply(SomeDto input) {
            return input.isValid();
        }
    }
```

I am aware about the [enum vs static final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel) topics, but is there any  real advantage of using enum's over static final with predicates or functions?

Comment: I am not sure about the advantages but there is a disadvantage from a readability point of view, `SOME_PREDICATE.apply(input)` is cleaner than `SomePredicate.INSTANCE.apply(input)`. Again, this is just me and not everyone will find a problem with the readability of the enum approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage of the `enum` singleton approach in this case is that the `Predicate`/`Function` is automatically `Serializable`.

Guava itself uses `enum`s for some of its `Predicate` and `Function` implementations for this reason, among others. Josh Bloch recommends the use of `enum`s when you want a singleton in Effective Java 2nd Ed., [Item 3](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=3). To quote:

> This approach is functionally equivalent to the public field approach, except that it is more concise, provides the serialization machinery for free, and provides an ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks. While this approach has yet to be widely adopted, a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton.

Guava exposes those singletons through static methods in its API though, avoiding the ugliness of `SomePredicate.INSTANCE` in user code.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the ways is more correct than the other.

If you read the previous answer at [What's the advantage of a Java enum versus a class with public static final fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel) you'll see that the enum approach has the advantage that it's easy to iterate over all possible values of the enum. However, in your case you have only one possible value, so this is not a benefit.

One advantage of the enum-based approach is that your class will have a prettier name and a name you can choose. In case you want to print the name of the class, this might be a deciding factor.