# better way to access static class fields

Tags: java

```
public final class Templates {
  public static class NewDeviceDetailsConsts {
        public static final String AAA = "aaaa";
        public static final String BBB = "bbbb";
        public static final String CCC = "cccc";
   }
   }
```

for using AAA, I have to write `Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts.AAA` and thats a long string to use 10-20 times in every class I use it.

Will it be efficient to use it like,
I define a field in classes I need it , `Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts DeviceConst;` and use DeviceConst.___ in the class. 
Is it fine or can I do it better than that.

Comment: Well you can always use a static import but, at some point, you will need to specify the fully classified name.

Comment: How about using top-level `enum` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `enum`'s for such purpose:

```
public final class Templates {
    public enum NewDeviceDetailsConsts {
        AAA("aaaa"), BBB("bbbb"), CCC("cccc");

        private String value;

        private NewDeviceDetailsConsts(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the constants as follows:

```
NewDeviceDetailsConsts aaa = NewDeviceDetailsConsts.AAA;
```

You can also use AAA, BBB, ... without param if you need as follows:

```
public final class Templates {
    public enum NewDeviceDetailsConsts {
        AAAA, BBBB, CCCC;
    }
}
```

And lastly, you should not define them inside a class. An enum can also be a top level class as follows unless they have to be part of a class:

```
public enum NewDeviceDetailsConsts {
    AAAA, BBBB, CCCC;
}
```

Comment: I came up with this `import static Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts.*`. I will use this and use the Consts directly. Is this approach better or should I go with enums?

Comment: The problem with `static import`s is that you pollute the namespace of your classes. Imagine you use them in lot of classes and let us assume the classes are more than a couple of lines long, then if you encounter a constant `AAA` in the code you do not directly see where it comes from. If you use them in class hierarchy they can cause error you might not see easily. As for me, I don't see any reason why I have to use static constants instead of `enums`. Enums are very powerful too.

Comment: If you are still looking for more information as to which variant to use [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969690/whats-the-advantage-of-a-java-enum-versus-a-class-with-public-static-final-fiel) you will find some very good explanations why you should consider using `enum`s. Not only the accepted answer but also others have very good explanations.

Answer (score 2):

There a a few ways you can solve this problem.

1. create a static import:

   Where your import statements are, add this `import static path.to.Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts.AAA;`. This will allow you to reference your `AAA` object just by typing `AAA`.

   Unfortunately, you will have to add this line at the top of all your classes.
2. Create a getter your `Templates` class.

   ```
   public static NewDeviceDetailsConsts getAAA(){
       return NewDeviceDetailsConsts.AAA;
   }
   ```

   Then use `Templates.getAAA()` to get the `AAA` object.
3. Save a reference to the `AAA` object inside the working class.

   ```
   private static NewDeviceDetailsConsts AAA = Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts.AAA;
   ```

Comment: I need all consts of 'NewDeviceDetailsConsts', in around 10 classes,which one will you suggest ?

Comment: Seeing as how you need to reference the objects in multiple classes, create the getters in your `Template`  class. This will allow you to access the objects no matter what class you're working in.

Comment: I came up with this `import static Templates.NewDeviceDetailsConsts.*`. I will use this and use the Consts directly. Is this approach better or should I go with getters ?

Comment: @tarun14110 that approach works perfectly well. The only drawback is you will have to add that at the top of each file, otherwise it's completely acceptable.