# How do I convert an integer to an enum in MyBatis?

Tags: java, enums, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have the following:

```
public class Stat {

    public enum HitType {
        MOBILE1(0), MOBILE2(1), DESKTOP(2);
        public final int value;
        public int value() { return value; }
        HitType(int val) {
            value = val;
        }
        public static HitType parseInt(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0: return MOBILE1;
                case 1: return MOBILE2;
                case 2: return DESKTOP;
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public HitType hitType;
    public long sourceId;

    public Stat(... int hitType, BigInteger sourceId) {
        this.hitType = HitType.parseInt(hitType);
        this.sourceId = sourceId.longValueExact();
```

---

```
@Mapper
public interface StatMapper {

    @Select("select * from stats where id = #{id}")
    @Results(value = {
        @Result(property = "hitType", column = "hit_type"),
        ...
        })
    public Stat findById(@Param("id") long id);
```

---

```
    Stat s = statMapper.findById(1);
    response.getOutputStream().print(s.toString());
```

It still gives this error:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'hit_type' from result set.
>    Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.company.app.model.Stat.HitType.2

I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878952/ddg#5878986 and read [Convert integer value to matching Java Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292790/convert-integer-value-to-matching-java-enum).

If I change the constructor signature to

```
public Stat(..., int hitType, long sourceId) {
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
```

Then it gives the error

> nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No constructor found in com.company.app.model.Stat matching [java.math.BigInteger, java.lang.String, java.sql.Timestamp, java.lang.Integer, java.math.BigInteger]

So it seems in the first case it may be setting properties directly, while in the 2nd case, it is using the constructor.

I tried putting `HitType hitType` in the constructor signature, but it still gives me the `No constructor found...` error.

MyBatis 3.4.5, MyBatis-Spring 1.3.1, Spring-Boot 1.5.13

Answer (score 0):

I added the getter & setter for that type

```
public HitType getHitType() {
    return hitType;
}

public void setHitType(int hitType) {
    this.hitType = HitType.parseInt(hitType);
}
```

And then it started working. Which is weird because it was complaining about the constructor signature. If it is using the constructor, why would it need the getters and setters?