# Using reverse values in enums in Java

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I have an enum with values like this (the example just shows a few of the values but you will catch on): _800, _830, _900, _24HOURS, CLOSED

These have a corresponding value, so I added to my enum, which you can do in Java, a value field and a getter and setter for the value, like this (for space sake I do not show the getter and setter but they are the standard ones):

```
 enum Hours {
    _800("08:00"),
    _830("08:30"),
    CLOSED("Closed"),
    APPT("By Appt.")
    // etc
    ;

    Hours(String v) {
        val = v;
    }
    String val;
 }
```

I also want to be able to go the other direction, that is, if I have a value (e.g. "08:00") I want it to return the enum _800.  So to the enum I added a map:

```
 static Map<String,String> valToEnumMap = new HashMap();
```

then I added this to my constructor:

```
    Hours(String v) {
        val = v;
        valToEnumMap.put(v, this);
    }
```

and a new method:

```
Hours valToEnum(String v) {
   return valToEnumMap(v);
}
```

but when I try running it I get an initialization error at the point where it tries to insert into the map.  I have tried other things like

```
 valToEnumMap.put(v, valueOf(name());
```

but the same error.  I did find a workaround but it is very slow, so I wonder what I did wrong?  Here is the workaround I used which is slow:

```
public static OfficeHoursTimes valToEnum(String val) {
        for (OfficeHoursTimes o : OfficeHoursTimes.values()) {
            if (o.getVal().equals(val)) {
                  return o;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

But there has to be a better way

Comment: Enums should be immutable, so please no setters

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use the map before it's initialized, since your enum instances get created first.

You want to declare your map like this:

```
static final Map<String,Hours> valToEnumMap = _createValueMap();
```

and then

```
private static Map<String,Hours> _createValueMap()
{
    Map<String, Hours> map = new HashMap<>();

    //...iterate through values() and put them all in the map ...

    return map;
}
```

Comment: >> The problem is that you're trying to use the map before it's initialized, since your enum instances get created first.  - that's not true, add logs and you'll see it

Comment: @AdamSkywalker According to my logs, Matt is right. Firstly, all enum instances are created. Static fields and static initializer go next.

Comment: @vojta  https://gist.github.com/AdamSkywalker/11b2c6fcc12a2076c83bbe90883c14bc

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, you misunderstand.  The map is a static field *in the enum class*

Comment: @AdamSkywalker see http://stackoverflow.com/a/444000/3899583

Comment: @MattTimmermans ahh, now it makes sence

Comment: Hey it looks like this will work.  For the static map instead of initializing it I just do a static Map<String,String> valToEnumMap;  And then my Constructor:

        Hours(String v) {
        val = v;
        if (valToEnumMap == null) { 
             valToEnumMap = new HashMap<>();
        }
        valToEnumMap.put(v, this);
    }

Comment: @Tony you can do that if the map isn't declared final... but don't -- that's gross

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems your map is defined wrong.

Try

```
static Map<String,Hours> valToEnumMap = new HashMap<String,Hours>();
```

Comment: sorry.  It is HashMap<>() not HashMap().  A typo.  It can infer the parameters from the map from the declaration.