# Iterate Enum by argument

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum, but i want to iterate over the second argument only without having to iterate over the enum member that are outside of this category, so if i have a `message`:"Message" and category `"Category"` i can specify the category as argument too in the method `isMessageInGroup` without having to iterate over those with another category like `MESSAGE_3`:"Another Category"

Is there a neat way to do it and save some iteration time? probably not even with a great deal of values this will affect performance noticeably, but i want to know if it possible. Searched for a bit but hard to find this specific question.

The Enum below does charge for messages by category but i want to know if i can avoid iterating over those outside the category wanted

```
public enum MessagesEnum {
    MESSAGE_1("Message", "Category"),
    MESSAGE_2("Another Message", "Category"),
    MESSAGE_3("Odd Message", "Another Category");

    private final String message;
    private final String category;

    SabreErrorMessages(String message, String errorCategory) {
        this.message = message;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public static boolean isMessageInGroup(String message){
        for(MessagesEnum message : MessagesEnum.values()) {
            if(message.contains(message.getMessage()) && message.getCategory().equals("Category")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just have a static final field with a `Map<String, List<SabreErrorMessages>>` that builds up a `Map` when the class is loaded.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is right, but perhaps with the caveat that it should maybe be a `Map<String, Set<String>>` since then you can check `contains` without iterating anything at all.

Comment: Got it, should've occurred to me with some creativity, there is always a smart way. Thank you both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments have said, an out-of-the-box enum won't be most efficient for this because you will have to use an iterator. `HashMap`, however, provides O(1) lookup on average and will be much faster.

```
public enum Messages {

    MESSAGE_1("Message", "Category"),
    MESSAGE_2("Another Message", "Category"),
    MESSAGE_3("Odd Message", "Another Category");

    private static final Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Messages m : Messages.values()) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(m.category, s -> new HashSet<>()).add(m.message);
        }
    }

    private final String message, category;

    private Messages(String message, String category) {
        this.message = message;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getMessage() { return message; }
    public String getCategory() { return category; }

    public static boolean isMessageInGroup(String message){
        // use `getOrDefault` if `get` could return null!!
        return map.get("Category").contains(message);
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/VLrEZm)

**Edit**: Should you choose to implement a method like `messagesInGroup`, the safest way would be to implement it using an unmodifiable `Set` so as to protect the integrity of the enum's internals.

```
public static Set<String> messagesInGroup(String category) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        map.getOrDefault(category, Collections.emptySet())
    );
}
```

Comment: There's no particular need to change it from being an enum. Enums work well with this solution.

Comment: @PaulHicks Yes, I was thinking about that. It's fixed now. I had to reference [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/443980/5743988) to figure out how to do it.

Comment: That's it. Though I doubt OP actually wants an `isMessageInGroup` method, that was just his attempt at a solution. Probably a more useful method would be `Collection<Message> MessagesInGroup(string category) { return map.get(category); }` which allows app code to do what it needs.

Comment: @PaulHicks Yes Paul, my solution ultimately should work for any category. I believe this is the most elegant way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisDurazo Notice that I used `computeIfAbsent` which is a Java 8 feature of `Map`. If you aren't using Java 8, you will need to replace that with what you have available.

Comment: @4castle yes, i'm acquainted with the java 8 features, didn't know of the existence of `computeIfAbsent` will read about it before using it as is, method name is very self explanatory though, just curious about how is implemented.

Comment: Oh good. In that case you might also want to use `getOrDefault` with the suggestion from @PaulHicks so that you don't return `null`. I didn't use `getOrDefault` because I knew it wouldn't return `null`. (Be careful using the suggestion from Paul though, because it would be possible for the calling scope to modify the `Collection` and ruin the integrity of the Enum, so you should wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`)

Comment: Does `Collections.emptySet()` work where you currently have `new HashSet<>()`?

Comment: @PaulHicks Yes, I'm going to update because that would actually be preferable since it returns a singleton (and therefore saves memory and speed instead of creating a new object). It can't be used in `computeIfAbsent` though because the `Set` it returns is immutable.